# What does the phrase "end over end" mean here?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Please help me figure out the meaning of the phrase "end over end" in the following text from the description of the game "Flip Runner":

Select the starting angle, then launch yourself end over end as you try to nail the perfect landing. Miss a mark and it’s rag-doll city, with your runner becoming a parkour pancake. (source)

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**End over end** is the same as "**head over heels**" and "**top over tail**". The nouns "**end**" refer respectively (i) to your head or top, and (ii) your heels or tail, as the ends of your body.

**OED**

> (b) **head over heels.** [...]
>
> (i) With reference to falling, tumbling [=gymnastics], etc.: so that one's heels are in the air and one's head is below them; so as turn completely over, as in a somersault; [to fall, jump or move] headlong. *Apparently arising from an inversion of the elements in the earlier phrase "heels over head" and "tail over top."*
>
> 1987   H. W. Pfanz Gettysburg: Second Day xv. 366   Its [sc. the shell's] burst sent Wilcox's remaining courier..flying head over heels.
>
> 2005   K. Hancock Shadow over Kiriath 355   He tumbled head over heels as if bowled toward shore by a powerful wave, then came suddenly upright and still.

Both **end over end** and **head over heels** usually refer to travelling a distance whilst falling in a quick and uncontrolled manner.